# Codemirror - adding new keywords to a syntax highlighting file

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I have just come across [Codemirror](http://codemirror.net/).

I would like to know how to create my own Syntax files (for a toy language), or extend the Syntax file of an existing language with new keywords - however, I can't find any documentation on how to get started.

Has anyone any links on docs that that show how to do this?

Answer (score 10):

http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html

In the second paragraph it says:
"The distribution comes with a few modes (see the mode/ directory), and it isn't hard to [write new ones](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#modeapi) for other languages."

So simply scroll down on that page to the "Writing CodeMirror Modes" part.

Answer (score 1):

> extend the Syntax file of an existing language with new keywords

You can also try the recently created [keyword.js](https://github.com/erosman/CodeMirror-plus) CodeMirror addon can for this purpose.